# what dose newshape (, -1) do?

Tags: python, function, numpy, reshape

could you explain the role of newshape in reshape and what dose `newshape=(n_channels, -1)` mean? I wanna use the below code to reshape my signal matrix, but I don't understand the last part

```
np.reshape(np.transpose(signal, axes=[1, 2, 0]), newshape=(n_channel, -1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, You want to [reshape your NumPy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with `10*2` dimension to `5*4`. You need:

```
a = np.zeros((10, 2)) # Generates 10*2 zero matrix
np.reshape(a, newshape=(5, 4))
```

This gives output like this:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

The same output can be produced by:

```
np.reshape(a, newshape=(5, -1))
```

Because the value for second dimension is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions. Here it will take 4, but if you want `2*10` array then you can use `newshape=(2,-1)` here second value will be 10.